# how to echo only one value either the value is multiple [PHP]

Tags: php, sql

im trying to display only one value of my database if the value is duplicate/multiple or have the same value in another row

example database

```
id | name | section
1  | ron  | ABC
2  | mark | B12
3  | nick | B12
```

this my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myusers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "$rows['section']"; 
}
```

Output : `ABC B12 B12`

i want output like this `ABC B12`

Comment: `distinct` in sql or `array_unique()` in php

Comment: thanks for your time, i already solved my problem using `distinct`. also i already tried `array_unique()` but it doesn't solved my wanted output. that's why i post this question

Comment: Probably you have used it incorrectly. Was a call like `array_unique(array_column($rows, 'section'))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only using one column, just select that column.  Then if you apply the `DISTINCT` keyword there will be no duplicates:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `section` FROM `myusers`";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myusers GROUP BY section";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the DISTINCT parameter in your Queen. Here is an article with how to: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct